About DhcpGetClientInfoV6 function in dhcpsapi.h
When I used the DhcpGetClientInfoV6 function in dhcpsapi.h, it returned code 2. After searching, I found the content, but I couldn't understand it.
$ .\Err_6.4.5.exe 2             

# for hex 0x2 / decimal 2 

  BTH_ERROR_NO_CONNECTION                                        bthdef.h 

  DEVICE_QUEUE_NOT_BUSY                                          bugcodes.h 

  CDERR_INITIALIZATION                                           cderr.h 

  CR_OUT_OF_MEMORY                                               cfgmgr32.h 

  DHCP_DROP_NOMEM                                                dhcpssdk.h 

  MD_ERROR_SUB400_INVALID_DEPTH                                  iiscnfg.h 

  MD_ERROR_SUB401_LOGON_CONFIG                                   iiscnfg.h 

  MD_ERROR_SUB403_READ_ACCESS_DENIED                             iiscnfg.h 

  MD_ERROR_SUB404_DENIED_BY_POLICY                               iiscnfg.h 

  MD_ERROR_SUB423_NO_CONFLICTING_LOCK                            iiscnfg.h 

  MD_ERROR_SUB502_PREMATURE_EXIT                                 iiscnfg.h 

  MD_ERROR_SUB503_APP_CONCURRENT                                 iiscnfg.h 

  IME_RS_NOIME                                                   ime.h 

# IME is not installed 

  RSVP_Err_POLICY                                                lpmapi.h 

  RSVP_Erv_Bandwidth                                             lpmapi.h 

# /* Insufficient bandwidth   */ 

  RSVP_Erv_No_Serv                                               lpmapi.h 

# /* Unknown Service      */ 

  RSVP_Erv_API                                                   lpmapi.h 

# /* API logic error */ 

  POLICY_ERRV_UNSUPPORTED_CREDENTIAL_TYPE                        lpmapi.h 

  POLICY_ERRV_GLOBAL_GRP_FLOW_COUNT                              lpmapi.h 

  MSIDBERROR_REQUIRED                                            msiquery.h 

# non-nullable column no null values allowed 

  NMERR_INVALID_HFILTER                                          netmon.h 

  SMART_INVALID_FLAG                                             ntdddisk.h 

# Invalid command flag 

  DS_NAME_ERROR_NOT_FOUND                                        ntdsapi.h 

  STATUS_WAIT_2                                                  ntstatus.h 

  ODBC_ERROR_INVALID_BUFF_LEN                                    odbcinst.h 

  MSDRI_S_MMI_PENDING                                            pbdaerrors.h 

  MFE_NOT_FORWARDING                                             routprot.h 

# not fwding for an unspecified reason 

  SCESTATUS_RECORD_NOT_FOUND                                     scesvc.h 

  SE_ERR_FNF                                                     shellapi.h 

# file not found 

  SNMP_ERRORSTATUS_NOSUCHNAME                                    snmp.h 

  SNMP_GENERICTRAP_LINKDOWN                                      snmp.h 

  ICERR_NEWPALETTE                                               vfw.h 

  WDSMCCLIENT_CATEGORY                                           wdsmcerr.h 

# WDS Multicast Client 

  WINBIO_FP_TOO_LOW                                              winbio_err.h 

# Position your finger higher on the fingerprint reader. 

  CMC_STATUS_FAILED                                              wincrypt.h 

  CMC_FAIL_BAD_REQUEST                                           wincrypt.h 

  DRM_S_MORE_DATA                                                windowsplayready.h 

  ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND                                           winerror.h 

# The system cannot find the file specified. 

  ERROR_LABEL_QUESTIONABLE                                       winioctl.h 

# Label could be invalid due to unit attention condition. 

  LDAP_PROTOCOL_ERROR                                            winldap.h 

  SNMP_ERROR_NOSUCHNAME                                          winsnmp.h 

# as an HRESULT: Severity: SUCCESS (0), FACILITY_NONE (0x0), Code 0x2 

# for hex 0x2 / decimal 2 

  WINBIO_FP_TOO_LOW                                              winbio_err.h 

# Position your finger higher on the fingerprint reader. 

# as an HRESULT: Severity: SUCCESS (0), FACILITY_NULL (0x0), Code 0x2 

  ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND                                           winerror.h 

# The system cannot find the file specified. 

# 43 matches found for "2"

The possible code is ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND in winerror.h.
However, after I changed the corresponding code in winerror.h and recompiled, the return code was still 2. I can't determine where the problem occurred. Please help.
This my code:
std::string LookupIPv6(const std::string& ip) {

    struct in6_addr addr;

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, ip.c_str(), &addr) != 1) {

        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid IPv6 address");

    }

    DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_V6 query;

    ZeroMemory(&query, sizeof(query));

    query.SearchType = Dhcpv6ClientIpAddress;

    memcpy(&query.SearchInfo.ClientIpAddress, &addr, sizeof(addr));

    LPDHCP_CLIENT_INFO_V6 result = nullptr;

    DWORD ret = DhcpGetClientInfoV6(nullptr, &query, &result);

    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS || !result) {

        FreeClientInfoMemoryV6(result);

        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to get DHCP client info, error code: " + std::to_string(ret));

    }

    char mac[64];

    BYTE* macData = result->ClientDUID.Data;

    snprintf(mac, sizeof(mac), "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",

        macData[0], macData[1], macData[2], macData[3], macData[4], macData[5]);

    FreeClientInfoMemoryV6(result);

    return std::string(mac);

}


editing a header won't change the behaviour of a compiled library, the documentation gives a list of return codes

The library was compiled before you changed the header file so changing the header file will not change the behaviour of the library. In fact you don't even know if the library uses that header file. Never change header files that do not belong to you, that's a sure recipe for confusion.

@AlanBirtles To be fair to the OP 2 is not one of the documented possible error codes.

My guess is that the problem is that you are passing nullptr as the first parameter to DhcpGetClientInfoV6. That parameter is supposed to be the ip address or hostname of your DCHP server. As far as I can tell from the documentation passing nullptr for that parameter is not permitted.

@john But When I use DhcpGetClientInfoV4 use nullptr it works fine

@haiyangtao Well I don't know, I am only guessing, but it seems to me that in both cases you are doing more than the documentation allows you to do, so the results are going to be unpredictable.

@haiyangtao Welcome to C++, that one call seems to work doesn't mean it is correct to call it with a nullptr you could be invoking undefined behavior (though ideally the library should have warned you nullptr is invalid input)

@john After I changed it to a domain name query, only ipv4 still works normally.@Pepijn Kramer

@haiyangtao "But When I use DhcpGetClientInfoV4 use nullptr it works fine" - DhcpGetClientInfoV4 is not documented as accepting nullptr, either. Do not use APIs in undocumented ways

Invalid IPv6 Format Provided
I found the issue: the IPv6 address I was using for the query was incorrect. After fixing it, the following code worked as expected:
int main() {
    DHCP_CLIENT_INFO_V6 clientInfo = { 0 };
    DHCP_IPV6_ADDRESS clientAddress = { 0 };

    // Correct IPv6 address: 2022::74c0:f5e6:feca:3fb3
    clientAddress.HighOrderBits = 0x2022000000000000;
    clientAddress.LowOrderBits = 0x74c0f5e6feca3fb3;
    clientInfo.ClientIpAddress = clientAddress;

    DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_V6 query{};
    query.SearchType = Dhcpv6ClientIpAddress;
    query.SearchInfo.ClientIpAddress = clientAddress;

    LPDHCP_CLIENT_INFO_V6 result{ 0 };
    DWORD ret = DhcpGetClientInfoV6(L"WIN-QI9RF26NQVN", &query, &result);

    if (ret == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        //
        // Process the result...
        //
    } else {
        std::cout << std::to_string(ret) << std::endl;
    }
}

To make the implementation more robust, I wrote a helper function to convert IN6_ADDR to DHCP_IPV6_ADDRESS:
// Converts IN6_ADDR to DHCP_IPV6_ADDRESS
static void convertToDHCPIPv6(const IN6_ADDR* in6Addr, DHCP_IPV6_ADDRESS* dhcpAddr) {
    if (!in6Addr || !dhcpAddr) return;

    dhcpAddr->HighOrderBits = 0;
    dhcpAddr->LowOrderBits = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        dhcpAddr->HighOrderBits = (dhcpAddr->HighOrderBits << 16) | ntohs(in6Addr->u.Word[i]);
    }
    for (size_t i = 4; i < 8; i++) {
        dhcpAddr->LowOrderBits = (dhcpAddr->LowOrderBits << 16) | ntohs(in6Addr->u.Word[i]);
    }
}

Here’s the complete, improved implementation:
static std::string LookupIPv6(const std::string& ip) {
    IN6_ADDR addr{};
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET6, ip.c_str(), &addr) != 1) {
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid IPv6 address");
    }

    DHCP_IPV6_ADDRESS clientIp;
    convertToDHCPIPv6(&addr, &clientIp);

    DHCP_SEARCH_INFO_V6 query{};
    query.SearchType = Dhcpv6ClientIpAddress;
    query.SearchInfo.ClientIpAddress = clientIp;

    LPDHCP_CLIENT_INFO_V6 result{ 0 };
    DWORD ret = DhcpGetClientInfoV6(DHCPSERVER, &query, &result);

    if (ret != ERROR_SUCCESS || !result) {
        std::string msg;
        switch (ret) {
        case ERROR_DHCP_JET_ERROR:
        case ERROR_DHCP_INVALID_DHCP_CLIENT:
            msg = "DHCP client not found.";
            break;
        default:
            msg = "Failed to get DHCP client info, error code : " + std::to_string(ret);
            break;
        }
        FreeClientInfoMemoryV6(result);
        throw std::runtime_error(msg);
    }

    char mac[128]{};
    BYTE* macData = result->ClientDUID.Data;
    size_t macLength = result->ClientDUID.DataLength;

    size_t len = macLength < sizeof(mac) / 3 ? macLength : sizeof(mac) / 3;

    char* macPtr = mac;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        int printed = (i == len - 1) ?
            snprintf(macPtr, sizeof(mac) - (macPtr - mac), "%02x", macData[i]) :
            snprintf(macPtr, sizeof(mac) - (macPtr - mac), "%02x:", macData[i]);
        macPtr += printed;
    }
    FreeClientInfoMemoryV6(result);

    return std::string(mac);
}

Issue: Status Code Returns 2
Although this code now works correctly, I am still unsure why the status code  returns 2. If anyone can provide insights into this specific error code, it would be much appreciated.
